# HtmlUnit not rendering Google Charts

Tags: javascript, java, google-visualization, htmlunit

I am having trouble getting a Google Charts page to render in HtmlUnit 2.19.

I have the following `java` code:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{
    String url = "http://localhost/chartsTest/test.html";
    WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    HtmlPage p = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Attempting to load page: " + url);
        p = wc.getPage(url);
        System.out.println("Sucsess!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to get page");
    }

    HtmlDivision div = p.getHtmlElementById("img");
    String content = div.asXml();
    System.out.println(content);

    div = p.getHtmlElementById("data");
    content = div.asText();
    System.out.println(content);

    wc.close();
}
```

and my `test.html` page is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                ['2013',  1000,      400],
                ['2014',  1170,      460],
                ['2015',  660,       1120],
                ['2016',  1030,      540]
            ]);

            var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart');
            var chart_img = document.getElementById('img');
            var chart_data = document.getElementById('data');

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(chart_div);

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
                var imgString = chart.getImageURI();
                chart_img.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgString + '">';
                chart_data.innerHTML = imgString;
            });

            chart.draw(data);

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="img"></div>
    <div id="data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this page in a web browser I get the svg chart, an image of the chart and then the png 64-bit string of the image.

However, when I run the java application the output I get is:

```
Attempting to load page: http://localhost/chartsTest/test.html
Oct 19, 2015 11:41:37 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 19, 2015 11:41:37 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 19, 2015 11:41:37 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 19, 2015 11:41:42 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/core/tooltip.css' [3:38] Error in pseudo class or element. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <IDENT>, ":", <FUNCTION_NOT>, <FUNCTION_LANG>, <FUNCTION>.)
Oct 19, 2015 11:41:42 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/core/tooltip.css' [3:38] Ignoring the whole rule.
Sucsess!
<div id="img">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,"/>
</div>

data:image/png;base64,
```

It appears that the image doesn't get loaded correctly.

If I were to put a log in the function which alters the divs, it only logs the `data:image/png;base64,` string when running the java application.

Comment: I had similar issue with Highcharts in HtmlUnit. I couldn't find any solution, so I had to change wed driver. So I've choose Selenium and use FireFox driver. So if you won't find any solution you at least can do that.